# How to save a matfile with structure to a matfile with just an array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, save, structure

I have a matfile named C875.004-03.B401.mat that contains a structure C1.  C1 is a 1X1 structure that contains 100 variables.  I want to remove the structure and save the matfile such that it is only an array of the 100 variables when I load it in matlab.  Any thoughts?  Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 4):

Or just use `save` with it's `-struct` option -

```
load('C875.004-03.B401.mat')
save('C875.004-03.B401.mat','-struct','C1')
```

It's there in the documentation from my MATLAB version -

```
-struct'

Keyword to request saving the fields of a scalar structure as individual variables in the file. The structName input must appear immediately after the -struct keyword.
```

It's there on the [Mathworks Help](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/save.html) too with example, as quoted here -

```
Create a structure, s1, that contains three fields, a, b, and c.

s1.a = 12.7;
s1.b = {'abc',[4 5; 6 7]};
s1.c = 'Hello!';
Save the fields of structure s1 as individual variables in a file called newstruct.mat.

save('newstruct.mat','-struct','s1');
Check the contents of the file using the whos function.

disp('Contents of newstruct.mat:')
whos('-file','newstruct.mat')
Contents of newstruct.mat:
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  a         1x1                 8  double              
  b         1x2               262  cell                
  c         1x6                12  char
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use class `matfile` which helps with loading and saving data to mat-files. Below is an example for your case. I assume that all variables are stored as an array in the single structure's field named `str`. Correct me if it is not the case.

```
matObj = matfile('/path/to/C875.004-03.B401.mat');
matObj.C1=matObj.C1.str;
```

Now, `C1` should be an array.